# Reading lines from file, printing only lines that have same amount of letters as user will choose

Tags: c, file

I am trying to write code where you will choose words that will be printed if they have same amount of letters that you will choose.

If you choose that you want to have printed only words that have 3 letters it will ignore longer or shorter words.

I have no idea, how to write a word if letter count is same as user wanted.

This is what I have so far.

```
do
{
   ch = fgetc( fp );

   if ( ch == ' ' || ch == EOF || ch == '\n' )
   {
      if(count == n) {
       /* Here should be printed the word */
      count = 0;
      }
      else count = 0;
   }
   else
   {
      ++count;
   }
} while ( ch != EOF );
```

Comment: You have to store the letters in an array so that you can print the content of the array when the word must be printed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must store the letters in an array so that you can print the content of the array when needed.

```c
char word[256];
do
{
   ch = fgetc( fp );

   if ( ch == ' ' || ch == EOF || ch == '\n' )
   {
      if(count == n) {
          /* Here should be printed the word */
          word[count] = '\0'; // terminate word
          printf("%s\n", word); // print word
          count = 0;
      }
      else 
          count = 0;
   }
   else
   {
      word[count] = (char)ch;  // save the characters
      ++count;
   }
} while ( ch != EOF );
```

Comment: Thank you so much, now it looks like my question is so dumb :D .